# How do I solve error "no module found named pyside2"?

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I am trying to run python file on my terminal and I get the error of "no module named **pyside2"**

I tried the to run the code which was already answered on similar type of question. But no changes on my side.

ERROR message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "xxx-qt.py", line 31, in <module>
from pyside2 import qtcore
Modulenotfounderror: NO module named "pyside2"
```

Comment: install pyside2 using `pip install PySide2`

Comment: It's hard to know what the problem is when you don't post the code/commands you've already run. However, one thing that pops out to me about this package is that it's a C package that needs to be compiled. Perhaps your system isn't properly compiling the package.

Comment: You misspelled 'PySide2' by using all lowercase letters.

Answer (score 15):

The problem arises because you haven't the module in your environment, you can install it using `pip install PySide2`

For more about PySide2: https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/

Answer (score 5):

You used all lower-case letters in your `PySide2` import statement.

The error message shows that your code imports using lowercase letters instead of mixed case:

```
NO module named "pyside2"
```

You probably installed PySide2 using all lowercase letters, `pip install pyside2`, but your code **must** import from: `PySide2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly the issue I was having

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by:

1. Repairing my Python installation
2. Deleting the virtual environment
3. Creating a new virtual environment
4. Running `pip install PySide2` in the new virtual environment

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it with the following way.

Reference from [Qt for Python & PyInstaller](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/deployment-pyinstaller.html)

> Since it has a UI, you use the –windowed option.
>
> The command line to proceed looks like this:

```
pyinstaller --name="MyApplication" --windowed hello.py
```

> This process creates two directories: dist/ and build/. The
> application executable and the required shared libraries are placed in
> dist/MyApplication.
>
> To run the application, go to dist/MyApplication and run the program:

```
cd dist/MyApplication/
./MyApplication
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there might be one of these two problems:

1. You have not installed PySide2, In that case you can install it using command **pip install PySide2**
2. The second is you have installed the Pyside2 but in one installation and trying to use it  from another installation, to tackle with this, **Create a virtual environment** for your project and install all modules in that virtual environment.

It's always a good idea to create virtual environment for project it will avoid breaking the base env. It avoid such kind of issues